# Reversing a CharIndex in a Stuff function to find and replace first occurrece of a character

Tags: sql, t-sql, charindex

I'm trying to find and replace the first space from right to left and replace it with a comma.

Before results: "Peter & Lois Griffin"

This is my current string:

```
SET [Last Name/Organization Name]=STUFF([Last Name/Organization Name],CHARINDEX(' ',([Last Name/Organization Name])),LEN(' '),',')
```

After results: `Peter, & Lois Griffin`

What do I need to change to make my results be: `Peter & Lois, Griffin` ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server at hand to test it, but you could take advantage of `REVERSE()`:

```
SET [Last Name/Organization Name]=STUFF(
    [Last Name/Organization Name],
    LEN([Last Name/Organization Name])-1-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE([Last Name/Organization Name])),
    LEN(' '),
    ',')
```

(plus you would have to treat empty string).

Comment: Thanks Mifeet. Your suggestion worked when I changed the -1 to +1. I'll still have to deal with other junk in the field like suffix. Thanks again.